# self-populating dependent select box

Tags: javascript

Hope this is a simple problem for you guys, I've spent days messing with this. I have a HTML page that allows the user to select a auto maker and once that's done, the dependent select box will populate with the options for that particular manufacturer.

This works perfectly in console log, I get all the options for each auto maker, but all I get in the actual HTML page is LAST model for each manufacturer. I've tried a number of different looping structures and various ways of writing / appending to the HTML without success. I've looked all over for JS that will work and most seem to run fine in the console log. How is this supposed to populate the HTML select box? Thanks in advance for your assistance.
Cheers,
Rick

CONSOLE.LOG

```
<option value="H8">Roadster</option>
<option value="I1">Model S</option>
<option value="I2">Model X</option>
<option value="I4">Model 3</option>
```

HTML

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="#">
<select name="model" id="model" oninput="getModels()">
<option value="none">Select a Make</option>
<option value="01">Acura</option>
</select>

<!-- Self-Populating -->
<select name="model" id="modelTgt">
</select><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function getModels(str) {
        var inPut = document.getElementById("model").value;

        // Must send it over to PHP page 
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("modelTgt").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    // CREATE THE myModels ARRAY AND USE IT WITH INNERHTML FOR OUTPUT
                    var myModels = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                    // run the loop to create <options>
                    for (var key in myModels) {
                        if (myModels.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            var front = '<option value="';
                            var mid = '">';
                            var last = '</option>\n';
                            document.getElementById("modelTgt").innerHTML = (front + key + mid +                        myModels[key] + last);  
                // console.log(front + inPut + second + key + mid + myModels[key] + last)
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "fns_get_models.php?q=" + inPut, true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlhttp.send('string');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you edit in what the response body is? The Array / Object that you're building from ?

Comment: Not sure why but the console.log is different to the innerHtml you want to add. Since you were saying that on console prints what you expect but not in HTML, could that be a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed how you were making the `<option>` elements, and had to make the Data myself but I assume you're looking to do something like this

You can use [`new Option(text, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) to create a new Option element and add it directly to your select. This also gives you an easy way to clear your select, by using `select.options.length = 0`, which could be helpful for dynamic population

```js
var myModels = {H8: 'Roadster', I1: 'Model S', I2: 'Model X', I3: 'Model 3'};

// if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  const select = document.getElementById("modelTgt");
  select.options.length = 0;
  
  for (var key in myModels) {
    if (myModels.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      select.options[select.options.length] = (new Option(myModels[key], key));
    }
  }
```

```html
<form role="search" method="get" action="#">
  <select name="model" id="model">
    <option value="none">Select a Make</option>
    <option value="01">Acura</option>
  </select>

  <!-- Self-Populating -->
  <select name="model" id="modelTgt">
    
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Light for your help! The tutorials I viewed didn't have this method, which is extremely slick and simple. I'll have to change my HTML code to send over more info than just the car model code - I was forced into a weird layout due to Bootstrap (had to line up other elements), but this will work!
Cheers,
Rick

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! Also, if this answer *has* helped you, could you mark it as accepted - This will reward both you and I with some reputation, and will mark your question as solved; you could also upvote if you want, but this isn't required - [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)